# Using method from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its possible to use a function from the parent component in a child component even if this function changes the parent state? (this function has a parameter)

How would i export it to my child component and use it?

**This is the function i want to export and use in my child component:**

```
function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
  return[...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
})
```

}

*Parent component:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Jumbotron, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Formulario from './Formulario'
import renderCadastros from './renderCadastros'

function App() {
  
  const [Cadastros, setCadastros] = useState([{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  }]) 
  
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return[...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
    })
  }

  return (
  
  <Jumbotron style={{background: 'transparent'}}> 
    
    <Formulario/>

    <Table striped bordered hover size='sm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
          <th>Nascimento</th>
          <th>Sexo</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}
      </tbody>
    </Table>

  </Jumbotron>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Child component:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {Button, Form, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'

function Formulario (){

  return(
    <div>
    <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Identificação</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Id" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Nome Completo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="João Silva" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>CPF</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="000.000.000-00" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="0.000.000" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Sexo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Masculino/Feminino" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
    </Form>
    <div  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button style={{margin: '10px'}} variant="primary">Cadastrar</Button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  )  
}

export default Formulario
```

*Thats other component from the application just so you can see it all:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function renderCadastros(cadastro, index){
    return(
    <tr id={cadastro.id} key={index}>
        <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
        <td align="center"><Button variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
    </tr>)
  }

  export default renderCadastros
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass functions down to child components via props, if the function alters state defined in the parent component, when that state has changed it React will re-render the parent and all its children.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);

  const increment = (num) => {
    setCounter(prev => prev + num)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Counter: {counter}</div>
      <Child increment={increment}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({increment}) {
  handleClick() {
    increment(1)
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment counter</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And If i were to use a parameter on that function, i just use It normally in my child?

Comment: You can't call the ```increment``` function inline as that would call it immediately when the component is rendered. You could have to pass a callback function. I've edited my answer able to demonstrate this.

Comment: Sorry Just a quick question on that, If i want to use This function in more than one component i can Just use It by doing the same way You showed up there? Using props

Comment: Yeah that would work given that the components are all children of the ```App``` component. Its too hard to point you in the right direction as I don't know what you're trying to build. I suggest you complete a Udemy React course, that will answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component you can pass down methods using props.

like this

```
//set your method to whatever you want to call it in your child component 

    <Formulario newFunction = {atualizarCadastros} />

then in your child component pass the prop at the top level like this

function Formulario ( {newFunction} ){

  return(
    <div>
    <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Identificação</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Id" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Nome Completo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="João Silva" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>CPF</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="000.000.000-00" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="0.000.000" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Sexo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Masculino/Feminino" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
    </Form>
    <div  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button style={{margin: '10px'}} variant="primary">Cadastrar</Button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  )  
}

export default Formulario
```

so whenever you want to call that function in your child just use newFunction. Hope this makes sense and helps!

Comment: And to use the parameter i simply do the same way i would use it in my parents component? Thanks!!

Comment: You sure can, the answer above mine shows how to pass down data if you need it as well. If you need to share this data or method across a bunch of components, look into the useContext hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function as a prop to the child component. 
Modify you map function to something like below

```
{Cadastros.map((item, index) => (
   <renderCadastros 
     cadastro={item} 
     key={index} 
     atualizarCadastros={atualizarCadastros} />
)}
```

And you can consume the data and function in the child component as below

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function renderCadastros({cadastro, atualizarCadastros}){
    return(
    <tr id={cadastro.id}>
        <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
        <td align="center"><Button variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
    </tr>)
  }

  export default renderCadastros
```

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Jumbotron, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Formulario from './Formulario'
import renderCadastros from './renderCadastros'

function App() {
  
  const [Cadastros, setCadastros] = useState([{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  }]) 
  
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return[...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
    })
  }

  return (
  
  <Jumbotron style={{background: 'transparent'}}> 
    
    <Formulario/>

    <Table striped bordered hover size='sm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
          <th>Nascimento</th>
          <th>Sexo</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Cadastros.map((item, index) => (
            <renderCadastros cadastro={item} key={index} atualizarCadastros={atualizarCadastros} />
        )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>

  </Jumbotron>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your function through props from the parent to child component. Reference as follows

**Parent Component:**

replace `<Formulario />` with `<Formulario atualizarCadastros={() => this. atualizarCadastros}`

*Arrow function used to bind.*

**Child Component:**

to access the function

```
function Formulario (props) {
   props.atualizarCadastros() // function call anywhere required
}
```

Comment: So with props i can call whatever method i Exported to my child by using "This"? Thanks!

Comment: yes, methods can be passed as props, these are like callback functions. This way can be used when we have any state changes on the parent component which depends on the child.